# mySQL: Subtracting months from date and using as condition in WHERE claus

Tags: mysql, database, time

With the following code I would like to determine if for location x, where a disruption occurred, a warning statement was issued in the time frame of six months prior.

In the where clause, I am using the `Date_Sub` function result as a condition:

```
SELECT disruption.disruptionDate, warning.warningID, warning.warningDate
FROM disruption
JOIN warning ON disruption.locationId = warning.locationID
WHERE warning.warningDate <= disruption.disruptionDate  
  AND warning.warningDate. >= DATE_SUB(disruption.disruptionDate, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY disruption.disruptionDate
```

Table Specifications:

- **warning Table**: 44,814 records
- **disruption Table**: 962,529 records

I am running into performance issues and think it might be caused by the `DATE_SUB` function in the WHERE clause. My research on here has yielded only Date_Sub as a subtraction method for months.

Is there a more efficient way to write the statement?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share the indexing details on your table(s). Also, share the `EXPLAIN` statement results.

Comment: Can you have warnings _after_ disruption date?

Comment: When you say performance issues, what do you mean by that ?  How much time does the query takes to run.

Comment: The query runs multiple hours, then fails. Warnings after disruptions are irrelevant for my analysis.

Comment: There is no where clause for disruptions table, not much room for optimization.